# Why does a GLKView not have a context?

Tags: ios, opengl-es

If I NSLog the class of my GLKView, I get GLKView but why then does it not have a context property that can be assigned an EAGLContext? Why do I have to cast it to another variable and then assign the EAGLContext?

Comment: You can directly do so. What is preventing you? is it giving you a compiler warning? an error while compiling? or exception on running?

Comment: Yes, if I specifically type in self.view.context = ...; I get an compile error: Property "context" not found on object of type UIView" (and of course autocomplete does not show context as an option in the first place).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing this within your `UIViewController` subclass, `self.view` is declared to return an object of type `UIView` So you have to cast it.  You can use:

```
((GLKView*) self.view).context = ...
```

Note that this assumes that `self.view` really is a `GLKView`.

Since `GLKViewController` doesn't define a `glkView` property, you could do that as:

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) GLKView* glkView;
-(GLKView*)glkView {
    return (GLKView*) self.view;
}
```

Comment: So you can cast it as you assign it. I didn't know you could do that. I gave it a try and works but I still find it strange that I need to cast it. The GLKView is with a GLKViewController but I guess what you are saying is technically true because  I looked at the hierarchy breakdown of the GLKViewController and it has a UIViewController within and the UIView is within that, which is subclassed as a GLKView.

Comment: `GLKViewController` inherits the `view` property from `UIViewController` so it gets the typing there.  With some similar cases they define a separate property that has the appropriate type (`UITableViewController` has a `tableView` property) but it doesn't look like they've done that with `GLKViewController`